# how to ask multiple selected question radio button/checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, radio-button

There should be three checkboxes/radiobuttons. When I click on one, the others should be grayed out. For example, when I click on someone, I have to make different selections. When I click on the other, different selections. How can I do that. For example, when I click on the first radio button. There should be a file upload button at the bottom. When you click on the second radio button, there should be text for writing. How can I do this with html css?

There should be a file upload button at the bottom. When you click on the second radio button, there should be text for writing. How can I do this with html css?

Comment: Hey, there. I see you're new so I suggesting taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also, please take a look at this article that explains [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which helps us to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

To do this with only HTML and CSS would be tricky, but to do this with JavaScript as well makes the task much simpler. The desired result can be created using HTML, CSS and JavaScript to hide and display the rest of the content once you click the specific radio button option.

In the below snippet, the JavaScript is listening for whether the radio button has been selected, and then displays the content for the selected radio button while first ensuring the other content is hidden.

```js
function Display(option) {
  var allContents = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
  for (var i = 0; i < allContents.length; i++) {
    allContents[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  
  var selectedContent = document.getElementById(option + 'Content');
  if (selectedContent) {
    selectedContent.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
.content {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="Option 1" value="option1" onchange="Display('option1')"> 
  <label for="radio1">Option 1</label><br>
  
  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="Option 2" value="option2" onchange="Display('option2')"> 
  <label for="radio2">Option 2</label><br>
  
  <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="Option 3" value="option3" onchange="Display('option3')"> 
  <label for="radio3">Option 3</label><br>
</div>

<div id="option1Content" class="content" style="display: none;">
  <p>Option 1 has been selected. Here is a file upload button:</p>
  <input type="file">
</div>

<div id="option2Content" class="content" style="display: none;">
  <p>Option 2 has been selected. Here is a text area for writing:</p>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div id="option3Content" class="content" style="display: none;">
  <p>Option 3 has been selected. Here is some placeholder content.</p>
  <img src="https://flif.info/example-images/fish.png" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="300" height="200">
</div>
```

Your question is hard to decipher, so if you have clarifications, please let me know via a comment or by editing your question to allow me to further assist you.